# Which flour or batter mixture gives the longest lasting, crispiest coating?

Tags: frying, deep-frying, batter

Given the choice between the following coatings and batters, which will give the crispiest, longest lasting crispy coating on deep-fried chicken breast pieces? The chicken will be fried once in an electric fryer for 4 minutes at 185C and will be in uniform, bite size pieces. The chicken will be seasoned, the dredges and batters will not.

(If there are any additives or combinations I have missed, please let me know. These are the most common flour-based coatings I know of. I have left breadcrumbs off the list as this requires a different coating technique to adhere to chicken properly (egg wash) from dredging alone.)

**Key:** [D] = Dredge, left to air dry for 15 minutes before frying
[B] = Batter, thick enough to coat and adhere to the chicken

1. Plain all purpose flour [D]
2. Plain all purpose flour + water [B]
3. Plain all purpose flour + alcohol (Beer, Vodka etc) [B]
4. Plain all purpose flour + beaten egg + water [B]
5. Self raising flour [D]
6. Self raising flour + water [B]
7. Self raising flour + alcohol (Beer, Vodka etc) [B]
8. Self raising flour + beaten egg + water [B]
9. Cornflour [D]
10. Potato starch [D]
11. Rice flour [D]
12. 50:50 mix Plain all purpose flour + Cornflour [D]
13. 50:50 mix Plain all purpose flour + Potato starch [D]
14. 50:50 mix Plain all purpose flour + Rice flour [D]

Comment: This sounds like an experiment *you* should do.  I doubt anyone has tried that many combos.

Comment: ATK uses flour, baking powder, and baking soda.  I don't have a membership, though, so I don't know what other mixes they tried: https://www.dallasnews.com/food/cooking/2016/11/08/this-is-the-ultimate-fried-chicken-recipe-that-has-inspired-top-chefs/

Comment: I have tried them all apart from rice flour and 50:50 split. The cornflour and potato starch lead out of the fryer, but I haven't tested for crispiness longevity. The ATK recipe I haven't heard of until now.

Comment: I just lined ATK becuase they're one of the sources that tries multiple recipes and explans which one worked best and why.  Or at least, they used to.